# Python: Get max pair in a list of pairs with min y

Tags: python, list, max, min

How i get max pair in a list of pairs with min y?

I got this list:

```
L =[[1,3],[2,5],[-4,0],[2,1],[0,9]]
```

With max(L) i get [2,5], but i want [2,1].

Answer (score 18):

```
max(L, key=lambda item: (item[0], -item[1]))
```

Output:

```
[2, 1]
```

Comment: I like this solution. Tuple expansion can also be used `max(L, key=lambda (x, y): (x, -y))`

Answer (score 1):

Your request is kind of cryptic, but I think this is what you want:

```
x, y = zip(*L)
maxPairs = [L[i] for i,a in enumerate(x) if a == max(x)]
returnPair = sorted(maxPairs)[0]
```

Comment: singularity's solution is the one you should use.

Answer (score 0):

```
import operator

get_y= operator.itemgetter(1)
min(L, key=get_y)[0]
```

Finds the coordinate with minimum *y*, retrieves *x*.

If you dislike `operator.itemgetter`, do:

```
min(L, key=lambda c: c[1])[0]
```